# physical address of variable in c

Tags: c, linux, virtual-memory

When we print the address a variable in c program, as per my understanding it displays the virtual address because every time it comes same (except for auto variables). Is there any way we can know the physical memory address. I am using Linux 32 bit machine.

Comment: There is no such thing as "physical address" or "virtual address" in the C language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no easy and portable way to do so.

The mapping between virtual and physical address happens via the memory management unit of your OS, which is free to move the data around as it sees fit.

Comment: And in particular, a variable may not even have a physical address at a particular instant in time, if the page containing that variable has been swapped out... Or it may have address X when you print it, but by the time it's made it to the screen and you've read it, it now has address Y instead.